# How to get value from database and set it to dropdown in php

Tags: php, mysql, html-select

[image for the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxTIm.png)i am trying to get value from database and set it to the dropdown box but it didnt get any value
here is my code

```
<?php
$sql=mysqli_query("SELECT RoomTypeId from roomtypemaster");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)){
echo '<select name="select">';
while($rs=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
      echo '<option value="'.$rs['RoomTypeId'].'">'.$rs['RoomTypeId'].'</option>';

  }
}
echo '</select>';
     ?>
```

Comment: check print_r(mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) there is data or no

Comment: first of all where is your database connection variable

Comment: mysqli_query requires at least two parameter

Comment: it displays value but not set to the dropdown

Comment: i have added the image

Comment: move select close tag to inside the if echo '</select>';

Comment: didnt display.the value shows outside the dropdown menu

Comment: You have a syntax error. Go google for "PHP mysqli select" - as already mentioned here, you need to pass the connection object to the query too. This code can't work, since mysqli is missing its second parameter and due will never return any data.

Answer (score 0):

**mysqli_query** function takes atleast two parameters. You didn't provide the connection variable while calling mysqli_query() function.

```
mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query)
```

As per PHP reference:

link: Procedural style only: A link identifier returned by mysqli_connect() or mysqli_init()

query: The query string.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// you should connect the database
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql=mysqli_query("SELECT RoomTypeId from roomtypemaster");
$result = $conn->query($sql);
//after this you will check  the number of rows from  your  database table
$count = mysqli_num_rows();
if($count>0){
   echo '<select>';
   while($data = $result->mysql_fetch_aasoc()){
    echo '<option value="'.$data['RoomTypeId'].'">'.$data['RoomTypeId'].'</option>';
   }
   echo '</select>';
}
?>
```